# Combine two text files into 1

Tags: c#

im completly new to c# well any kind of programming so any help will be appreciated.

i have two txt files that i wish to combine into one
the format is as follows:

```
text1.txt  
apple=1  
grape=2  
strawberry=3  
etc....

text2.txt  
1=156  
2=26  
3=180  
etc...
```

and the format i wish to achieve is

```
Final.txt  
apple=156  
grape=26
strawberry=180
```

im not too sure how to about this, i was thinking about splitting each line by '=' and using an if statement, but that doesnt seem to work, well i could not get it to work.

ideally if this could be done withing the same button void that would br great.
can somebody point me in the right diredction

cheers

Comment: first i though about ReadAllLines of both txt files then doing a foreach, but ended up with a foreach within a foreach and just ended up with complete nonsense in the finished txt file

Comment: If that was me, I would stream read both files to a `List<string>`, and assuming they both have the same number of lines, I would then substring the values to the left of the `=` character, and the proceed to stream write those back out.

Comment: That's one way to do it. nested for eaches are a good first pass. you should post that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse both files into Dictionaries:

For each file, use `File.ReadAllLines` to get a string array.

Then use a `foreach` to loop through each string in the array. Use String.Split on each string as you suggested to get a key and a value ("apple" and "1", for example). Add the key and value to a dictionary (one dictionary per file).

Then `foreach` through text1's dictionary, and use the value as the key for text2's dictionary. That lets you map "apple" -> 1 -> 156.

Write each line out to final.txt as you loop through the dictionary.

---

For example try this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String path1 = @"C:\file1.txt";
        String path2 = @"C:\file2.txt";
        String newFilePath = @"C:\final.txt";

        // Open the file1 to read from. 
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path1);

        // Add file1 contents to dictionary (key is second value)
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryA = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            string[] parts = s.Split('=');
            dictionaryA.Add(parts[1], parts[0]);
        }

        // Open the file2 to read from. 
        readText = File.ReadAllLines(path2);

        // Add file2 contents to dictionaryB (key is first value)
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryB = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            string[] parts = s.Split('=');
            dictionaryB.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }


        // Create output file
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(newFilePath);

        // write each value to final.txt file
        foreach (var key in dictionaryA.Keys)
        {
            if (dictionaryB.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                file.WriteLine(dictionaryA[key] + "=" + dictionaryB[key]);
            }
        }

        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: hope you don't mind but I added example code.

Comment: @PortlandRunner that should really be an answer of your own. Also, I was trying to give hints without the actual code.

Comment: I understand, I was trying to learn myself and by the time I came back the question was closed so I couldn't answer.  Feel free to delete

Comment: No worries, I'll leave it until such time as the question is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

- Read file 1 into a dictionary using IO.File.ReadAllLines, splitting by `=`, everything to the left is the key, everything to the right is the value.
- Read file 2 into a dictionary using the same approach.

Loop through all entries in the first dictionary, and for each value TryGetValue it in the other dictionary. If found, output a line into your output file, taking `key1` and `value2` (key of the first dictionary and value of the second one) - via the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `text1.txt` as a list of keys, and `text2.txt` as a list of values, you could simply read the first file line by line into a dictionary, say, `dictKeys`, and read the second file into another dictionary, `dictValues`.  Then you can loop over the `dictKey` and pull the values from the `dictValues` into a new dictionary.

At that point, just loop over the new dictionary and write it to a file.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictKeys = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<int, int> dictValues = new Dictionary<int, int>();

using (var r = new StreamReader("text1.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var splitLine = line.Split(',');
        dictKeys.Add(splitLine[0], Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[1]));
    }
}

using (var r = new StreamReader("text2.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var splitLine = line.Split(',');
        dictValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[0]), Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[1]));
    }
}

Dictionary<string, int> dictCombined = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var item in dictKeys)
{
    var keyVal = item.Value;
    if (dictValues.ContainsKey(keyVal))
        dictCombined.Add(item.Key, dictValues[keyVal].Value);
}

using (var w = File.OpenWrite("Final.txt"))
{
    foreach (var item in dictCombined)
        w.WriteLine("{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```